# How to enable Next/back button in wizard page in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my wizard page, the Next and Back buttons are not visible. is there any method to be called to make that enable?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add multiple Wizard pages to the wizard? If there is only a single page, it makes sense to remove the mentioned buttons.

**Update**:
If there are multiple pages, then look at the Wizard implementation, and check the [needsNextAndPreviousButton](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/IWizard.html#needsPreviousAndNextButtons()) method what it describes. If you have implemented the IWizard interface directly (and not using some convenience abstract class, such as Wizard), it is possible that you generated that method returning constant false.

If that did not help, I suggest looking at the tutorial http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JFaceWizards/index.html

Comment: Ya I do have to add another page to wizard, that's why I'm trying to get that.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `needsNextAndPreviousButton` method in the wizard constructor. If you've added pages in your wizard then check `canFlipToNextPage`, `isPageComplete`, and validate your page completion in these methods and enable/disable as well.